# Can I optimize this piece of code (SOQL query)?

Tags: apex, soql

Is it possible to optimize this code?

I have 2 objects:

ParentObj: The parent object

ChildObj: The child object

My code is as follows:

```
List<ChildObj__c> result = [SELECT ID, ParentObj__r.ID FROM ChildObj__c];
Set<ID> parentIDs = new Set<ID>();
for(ChildObj__c element: result){
    parentIDs.add(result.ParentObj__r.ID);
}
List<ParentObj__c> parentList = [Select ID from ParentObj__c where id in:parentIDs];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the subquery!

```
List<ParentObj__c> parentList = [Select ID 
                                 From ParentObj__c 
                                 Where id IN (SELECT ParentObj__c FROM ChildObj__c)];
```

You can read more about [Semi-Joins with IN and Anti-Joins with NOT IN](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm#semi_and_anti)